# The real difference between web and native apps in mobile and smart devices

Tags: interfaces, mobile

I still don't understand the difference between a native app and web or hybrid apps from the interface point of view. Now, apps such as Twitter, Facebook, etc. Are they native? or web? or hybrid apps? In those apps what is the most code was used? is it HTML and JS? or is it a language such as Objective C or Java?

I'm still confused.

Comment: Unlike web apps, native apps don't need a browser pretty much just like the desktop, but can be made to look very similar to the users, so jquerymobile for example makes the interface look the same. Web apps can even be downloaded and installed, so even from that perspective they're difficult to tell apart.

Comment: This is difficult. How can I know which one is more appropriate for my goals?

Comment: By doing some research.

Comment: You're not going to know 100% before you start building. A web app is easier to run on multiple platforms (Apple, Android), but a native app will not, so get ready to learn Objective C and Java. Mobil apps typically are not able to be sold on app stores unless they are contained inside a native app (hybrid). Plenty here for you to research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Native applications use Objective C or Java.  Web applications use HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript, running in a browser.

Native applications may have to be written more than once, to satisfy the native platform's specific demands, such as programming language.

Web applications may have limited access to the underlying native platform, and may not perform as well as their native counterparts.

Some vendors provide toolchains that allow you to create native applications once, and run them on multiple platforms.  In some cases, they do this by creating a web application and providing a common underlying API to target.